# Reading from rs232 port with C

Tags: c, serial-port

I am trying to correctly read from a rs232 com port, which is fetching info from a truck weight scale. I know that the weight scale sends out roughly 10x the weight per second, and it does not need any input, it just constantly send it out.

I can read the weight already but the problem is that I cannot read a **single line only** of the text that is sent by the weight scale. So I was hoping that someone might shape up a litle the C code so that it reads a single line.

By the way, I found the source code [here](http://www.teuniz.net/RS-232/), it is not mine.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <Windows.h>
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#endif

#include "rs232.h"



int main()
{
  int i, n,
      cport_nr=0,        /* /dev/ttyS0 (COM1 on windows) */
      bdrate=9600;       /* 9600 baud */

      unsigned char buf[4096];

      char mode[]={'8','N','1',0};


      if(RS232_OpenComport(cport_nr, bdrate, mode))
      {
printf("Can not open comport\n");

return(0);
}

while(1)
{
  n = RS232_PollComport(cport_nr, buf, 4095);

  if(n > 0)
  {
    buf[n] = 0;   /* always put a "null" at the end of a string! */

    for(i=0; i < n; i++)
    {
      if(buf[i] < 32)  /* replace unreadable control-codes by dots */
      {
        buf[i] = '.';
      }
    }

    printf("received %i bytes: %s\n", n, (char *)buf);
  }

  #ifdef _WIN32
      Sleep(100);
  #else
      usleep(100000);  /* sleep for 100 milliSeconds */
  #endif
  }

  return(0);
}
```

So, what I would like to accomplish here is that this C program should read a single line from the weight scale, outputs it and then exits. The line, should be 'marked' with delimiters, something like `EOL` or `##` or something else. Thanks in advance

EDIT1:
 - sample output of each one of the scales -

```
1st:
000000.,001000001,99
000000.,001000001,99
000000.,001000001,99
000000.,001000001,99
000000.,001000001,99

2nd:
+      0.0
+      0.0
+      0.0
+      0.0
+      0.0

3rd:
+       0
+       0
+       0
+       0
+       0
+       0
```

EDIT2:
Ok, i've found the scale rs232 protocol manual.
this is the corresponding table of the scale's protocol

```
   Data  |  ascii code  |  Description
    SP          20h        white space
    D6          0-9        1st weight digit
    D5          0-9        2nd "
    D4          0-9        3rd
    PD          2Eh        decimal mark
    D3          0-9        4th weight digit
    D2          0-9        5th "
    D1          0-9        6th "
    CR          0Dh        carriage return
    LF          0Ah        line feed
```

Comment: Post sample output of your code.

Comment: I think you need to understand the protocol the scale is using when it sends data.  In order for your code to be able to read a single line you have to know how big a single line is or what delimits a single line.  You are telling the code to read up to 4096 bytes.  Typically a protocol would send 1 or two bytes at the start of a record indicating the size of the data that can be read.  The secrete is probably in those pesky 'unreadable' control codes.

Comment: @chux please see edit1. thanks

Comment: Just write the code the way you specified it.  Keep reading until you get a \n, *then* print it.  Get rid of the sleep nonsense, that just hides bugs.

Comment: @Hans Passant, I would if I could but I just started learning C 3 days ago. I'm about to go to the getch() and getche() page lol. The way you said it looks pretty simple, and I believe it is. But I was never a C guy.. so it makes it really hard for me to do it .. Thanks for the tip anyway :)

Comment: @JJF, I know, you are right. Unfortunatelly, I don't have the scale protocol manuals here with me, but I will try to get them. Thanks.

Comment: Posted protocol does not match any of the 3 scale outputs.

Comment: The received data is ASCII text terminated by line control characters.  The approach you're taking is only appropriate for Windows.  If you're using Linux, then the simple input method would have Linux buffer the data for you and parse for the line termination, i.e. use a canonical **read()** that returns an entire line in your buffer.

Answer (score 1):

The key issue is that the data is arriving *asynchronously* to when code is searching for it - data arrives when it will - code is looking for data with no timing relationship to arrival.

So when code seeks a message with `RS232_PollComport()`: zero, a partial, a complete, or complete and partial messages may result.

Various approach depending on performance goals: let us try a simple one: look for `' '` and continue printing until `'\n'`.

```
void Service_Port(int cport_nr) {
  char *front_delimiter = "<";
  char *end_delimiter = ">";
  int start_of_frame = ' ';
  int end_of_frame = '\n';
  int start_of_frame_found = 0;
  for (;;) {
    char buf[1];
    int n = RS232_PollComport(cport_nr, buf, sizeof buf);
    if (n > 0) {
      if (buf[0] == start_of_frame) {
        fputs(front_delimiter, stdout);
        start_of_frame_found = 1;
      }
      if (start_of_frame_found) {
        fputc(buf[0], stdout);
        if (buf[0] == end_of_frame) {
          fputs(end_delimiter, stdout);
          return;
        }
      }
    }
  } // end for
}
```

The above spends *a lot* of time looping and waiting for a `'\n'`.

Various improvements possible, yet this meets OP's goal of

> read a single line from the weight scale, outputs it and then exits ...  The line, should be 'marked' with delimiters

Comment: Hi, can you please check my EDIT2? I believe that I should be trying to find 0Dh or 0Ah?? from the output? But will C read these ascii codes directly from the output? or how can i read them? Thanks

Comment: *"data is arriving asynchronously to when code is searching..."* -- Irrelevant since the OS will buffer the data for the user program.  Since the data is ASCII text, there's no need to getch() individual bytes and search for *"start of frame"*.  Use a system call to read complete lines (aka canonical read).

Comment: @sawdust C does not specify `RS232_PollComport()` nor does OP provide much detail. The existence of a "system call to read complete lines" is not known to exist for OP.  Certainly the best solution to read a line is to call a system function that reads a line.  Given OP is having issues, the reasonable assumption is that that function does not exist and `RS232_PollComport()` does not do line buffering.  Thus the reading of asynchronous data and putting into a line is relevant.

Comment: *"the reasonable assumption is that that function does not exist"* -- Wrong, the serial-port "library" that the OP is using is portable for either Windows or Linux.  So the OP is not running bare-metal but using a PC OS that supports a read syscall.  Certainly Linux supports a canonical blocked **read()**.