Got scrambled text when reading rs232 in virtualbox
I'm trying to read serial port data from my Ubuntu guest (The host is Windows & I'm using VirtualBox).
When I used Termite on my Windows host I could see the correct message, but when I used the debugging tool in Linux guest I only saw scrambled text like this.
Image: Using Termites on Windows host working just fine
Image: Got scrambled text when running demo code
I've also tried to use different baud rate to test it out and got no luck. Also, shouldn't it be the same baud rate that I used in the Windows host? The one that allows me to see the correct message in Termite. Any idea of where I should look?
For reference here's the demo code I'm using in Linux from https://www.teuniz.net/RS-232/.
Image: Also got scrambled text from this Debugging tool, https://www.teuniz.net/serial-com-tester/index.html
/**************************************************

file: demo_rx.c purpose: simple demo that receives characters from the serial port and print them on the screen, exit the program by pressing Ctrl-C

compile with the command: gcc demo_rx.c rs232.c -Wall -Wextra -o2 -o test_rx

**************************************************/

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <Windows.h>
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#endif

#include "rs232.h"



int main() { int i, n, cport_nr=2,        /* /dev/ttyS2 (COM3 on windows) */ bdrate=921600;       /* 9600 baud */

unsigned char buf[4096];

char mode[]={'8','N','1',0};


if(RS232_OpenComport(cport_nr, bdrate, mode, 0))   { printf("Can not open comport\n");

return(0);   }else{ printf("Open COM %d on Windows\n", cport_nr+1);   }

while(1)   { printf("RS232_PollComport...\n"); n = RS232_PollComport(cport_nr, buf, 4095);

if(n > 0)
    { buf[n] = 0;   /* always put a "null" at the end of a string! */

for(i=0; i < n; i++)
      { if(buf[i] < 32)  /* replace unreadable control-codes by dots */
        { buf[i] = '.';
        }
      }

printf("received %i bytes: %s\n", n, (char *)buf);
    }

#ifdef _WIN32 Sleep(100);
#else usleep(100000);  /* sleep for 100 milliSeconds */
#endif   }

return(0); } 


Looks like you copied code from https://www.teuniz.net/RS-232/   and used in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33674052/reading-from-rs232-port-with-c, but without any attribution and really messed up the formatting.

@sawdust I just added all of the attribution to the post. Sorry for that.

Welcome to SO. Please fix that formatting. Without proper indentation and some missing line breaks, it is barely readable. Readability is important. Especially for beginners.

if(buf[i] < 32) You might want to take a look at isprint function from ctype.h

Minimum things that need to be correct in serial are: baud rate, bits per character, parity, stop bits, and flow control. Any of these being incorrect will give garbled output.

Hi @Gerhardh, sorry that I'm not an English native speaker. I tried to edit this post a couple of times to make it readable.

Hi @stark, yes, I do use the same setting as the Termite, which I used in Windows and works just fine while in VM I always get the scrambled text. I'm wondering if there're other factors could possibly make a difference in serial communication between VirtualBox and Windows.

I am talking about your code.

after a few debugging. We found out that it's probably caused by high-speed serial communication, which VirualBox doesn't support. We were using a 921600 baud rate and always got garbled text, but after changing it down to 115200, it works! We'd like to do further testing to see if not using a virual machine will allow us to go back to the high-speed baud rate that we need.
